# Getting Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag when parsing Base64 encoded schema

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry, protobuf-java

I'm relying on Confluent's schema registry to store my protobuf schemas.

I posted the following schema in the schema registry:

```
{
"schema": "syntax = 'proto3'; package com.xyz.message; option java_package = 'com.xyz.message'; option java_outer_classname = 'ActionMessage'; message Action { reserved 7; string id = 1; string version = 2; string action_name = 3; string unique_event_i_d = 4; string rule_i_d = 5; map<string, Value> parameters = 6; string secondary_id = 8; message Value { string value = 1; repeated string values = 2;  } }",
"schemaType" : "PROTOBUF"
}
```

I then query the schema registry REST API from my application to retrieved it

```
...
JsonElement schemaRegistryResponse = new JsonParser().parse(inputStreamReader);
String schema = schemaRegistryResponse.getAsJsonObject().get("schema").getAsString();
```

This indeed makes **schema** variable holding a string containing the protobuf schema. I now want to create a **com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor** instance from it.

I proceed as follows:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(schema.getBytes());
FileDescriptorSet set = FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(encoded);
FileDescriptor f = FileDescriptor.buildFrom(set.getFile(0), new FileDescriptor[] {});
Descriptors.Descriptor descriptor = f.getMessageTypes().get(0);
```

However, this throws a **Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag** exception when invoking **parseFrom(encoded)** method.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse a base64-encoded representation of a .proto file. That's not at all what `FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom` expects. It expects a *protobuf binary representation* of a `FileDescriptorSet` message, which is typically created by `protoc` using the `descriptor_set_out` option.

I don't believe there's any way of getting the protobuf library to parse the text of a .proto file - you really need to run protoc.

Comment: then how does the Schema Registry does it? :x

Comment: @nmpg: Which schema registry do you mean, precisely? The Confluent one? It may well be running protoc behind the scenes.